docker container sqlite error on M1 ARM architecture
Creating a Docker container from an image that runs SQlite resulting in errors on an ARM architecture M1 pro macbook.
This is one of two dockerfiles. The front-end dockerfile runs fine. This dockerfile aims to run express.js (back-end) which talks to the Database (db.js).
FROM node:14

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    make \
    g++ \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Rebuild SQLite3 module
RUN npm rebuild keinos/sqlite3 --build-from-source

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Command to run the application
CMD ["node", "express.js"]

docker run -d --name pizzaserver3 -p 3004:3004 pizza-server

Log output:
2024-06-16 23:37:26 /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:57
2024-06-16 23:37:26       throw err;
2024-06-16 23:37:26       ^
2024-06-16 23:37:26 
2024-06-16 23:37:26 Error: /app/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node: invalid ELF header
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1173:18)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at bindings (/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:1:37)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
2024-06-16 23:37:26     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32) {
2024-06-16 23:37:26   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2024-06-16 23:37:26 }
2024-06-16 23:37:35 /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:57
2024-06-16 23:37:35       throw err;
2024-06-16 23:37:35       ^
2024-06-16 23:37:35 
2024-06-16 23:37:35 Error: /app/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node: invalid ELF header
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1173:18)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at bindings (/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:1:37)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
2024-06-16 23:37:35     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32) {
2024-06-16 23:37:35   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2024-06-16 23:37:35 }

Tried various methods

changing Node to Alpine version, to not affect


Error: /app/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node: invalid ELF header (ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED) usually means the file came from a different OS.
You're likely missing a .dockerignore with a node_modules line preventing it from being copied from you local box into the image.
